# Rails validating that a Has Many relationship has at least 1 entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an event model. Each event can have multiple sessions.

I want to ensure that no model can exist without it having at least 1 session associated with it.

```
  validates :sessions, :length => { :minimum => 1 }
```

The problem is - when I go to try to create sessions on a particular event by calling my model method:

```
create_sessions()
```

Which does something like :

```
sessions.create(event_id: id,date: x,day_of_the_week:x.strftime("%A"),classPin: pin)
```

for each of the dates the event will run.

It fails to save with the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved in EventsController#create
You cannot call create unless the parent is saved
```

Of course - by this point the new event record has not yet been saved - so this association cannot yet be created due to create on an association not available until the parent is saved!

Therefore how does any validation between this kind of relationship work - because the validation occurs at save time....but I want to validate the count of sessions will be greater than 0 before we save the event!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a simpler way would be to create your events and sessions with `new` instead of `create` it will only create the objects but not store them to the database. And after you have created your sessions do a `save` on your event.

```
@event = event.new(event_args)
@event.sessions.new(session_args)
@event.save
```

**Addition**
The `@event.save` will store the `@event` object and all associated `session` objects. Without further configuration only *new* objects will be safed see [Active Record Autosave Association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html) for more information.

Comment: Will the session validation happen during the event save as well?

Comment: The sessions will not be validated by default on `save` you will need to add `validates_associated :sessions` see the [Rails Validation Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated).

Answer (score 2):

The main point is that your validation conflicts with the way ActiveRecord works. You are creating a paradox.

There are a number of solutions, but you must relax the validation. That is, it should not run when the record is new.

You can either define it like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :sessions, length: { minimum: 1 },
                       unless: :new_record?
end
```

Or, to have even more flexibility, you can use a custom validation:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :session_count_validation

  private

  def session_count_validation
    if !new_record? && sessions.count < 1
      errors.add(:base, "Not enough sessions!")
    end
  end
end
```

This second style also has the advantage of being more performant: `sessions.count` will simply count how many associated `Session` records exist, while your original validation will **load all of them in memory**, and check the length of the relation/array.

Then, to ensure that your creation logic is sound, you should use a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html):

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    event = Event.create!(args)

    sessions = dates.map do |date|
      event.sessions.build(event_id: id,
                               date: date,
                    day_of_the_week: date.strftime("%A"),
                           classPin: pin)
    end

    sessions.each(&:save!)
  end
rescue
  # your rescue logic
  # e.g. display an error to the User
end
```

So that everything will be safely rolled back if any `save!` operation fails.